# Users forced to login while accessing facebook wall or fan pages on mobile devices

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-wall

Since last week, users are forced to login page while accessing our facebook wall or fan pages in mobile browsers. It works great on regular browsers. Why this sudden change on mobile devices.

Wall pages were always viewable except you have some age restrictions in the Settings. Now all of a sudden facebook started forcing users to login ?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open safari browser on Iphone
2. Open https://m.facebook.com/socialtwist
3. User is navigated to facebook login page

NOTE:Until the week before it was working, users were able to view the facebook walls without loggging in.(They use to see a Signup and Login buttons)

User should be able to view the wall page without logging in. This works on regular browsers for both m.facebook.com/socialtwist  and www.facebook.com/socialtwist

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed the same thing with my Facebook page.  Obviously they changed the rules on us, again.  As an alternative, you can get the RSS feed for your Facebook Fan Page and display your content to the mobile device that way.  See this article for how to get the RSS feed:

http://just-ask-kim.com/facebook-fan-page-rss-feed-url/#.UYAzeILzMWQ

Comment: Facebook has fixed this now.